# insert special character into SQL Server 2008 database from c#

Tags: c#, sql

i want to insert special character into sqlserver 2008 database. for example ('/@#&*$) etc.

i have tried the following code but it remove these string from the orignal string.

```
string[] arrtime = postingtime.Split(',');
                            string sss = arrtime[1];
                            string sss1 = "EDT";
                            bool first2 = true;
                            string s33 = Regex.Replace(sss, sss1, (m) =>
                            {
                                if (first2)
                                {
                                    first2 = false;
                                    return "";
                                }

                                return sss1;

                            });
```

But i didnt want to remove these string from the orignal string...because i want to insert a franch language data and removal of these special character will change the meaning of sentence.

my insert query is:

```
  cn.Open();
        adp.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into ttt values('r=DE'S''C/pa-ge=1/$@')", cn);
        adp.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
```

when i click on insert button then it gives error(datatype error). 
my problem is , to insert string with special characters not to remove these character. i want to pass these characters to our sql server 2008 from c# application.
thanx in advance

Comment: That's what you get for not using parameteried queries.

Answer (score 3):

Use parameterized queries like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ttt values (@testvalue)", cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testValue", "r=DE'S'C@4593§$%");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives the following error...String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated. i have used nvarchar() on sqlserver side....but still error.

Comment: Well, how long's the field in the database?

Comment: @user2499974 well, what **exactly** is the column type you are using? Based on the data, it should be at least `nvarchar(16)`

Comment: nvarchar(150), its size is 150

Comment: @user2499974 and the exact string you are trying to insert is the one shown in this answer? the one with 16 characters?

Comment: the exact string that i m trying is: [http://duproprio.com/search/?hash=/g-re=8-1-17-114-12-9-5-11-14-15-13-4-16-31-6-10-7-115-3-257-2/s-pmin=0/s-pmax=99999999/s-build=1/s-days=/s-filter=forsale/p-con=main/p-ord=date/p-dir=DESC/pa-ge=1/]

Comment: @user2499974 A string of almost 200 characters obviously cannot fit in a database field that specifies that no more than 150 characters may be entered...

Comment: make your field `nvarchar(1024)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters

```
adp.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into ttt values(@p1)", cn);
adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = "r=DE'S''C/pa-ge=1/$@";
```

Comment: it gives the following error....[String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated].

Comment: increase your column size something like `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Answer (score 1):

Your Insert query vunlerable to SQL injections.. Try using SqlParameters. and in SQLServer User NVarchar  datatype.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ttt values(@paramValue)", con))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramValue", "r=DE'S'C@4593§$%");
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
```